# How to encode HTTP POST parameters (C# client to PHP Server)?

Tags: c#, php, json, httpwebrequest

I'm having trouble figuring out the best way to encode the POST parameters to a server call.  I writing a C# client that will be served by a PHP server.  I want to allow a great deal of flexibility in the parameters, so my current plan is to have a single parameter that I use JSON to encode.  For example:

```
params = {"object":"Main","function":"doecho","params":["echothis...."]}
```

I'm using the C# WebRequest object and contentType of "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8".  The data gets to the server and everything works as expected until I add illegal JSON characters in the data.

For example, if I use the following data, then I can't do a json_decode on it on the server side.  The server appears to automatically turn the %40 into a double-quote (") when I read it with  $this->getRequest()->getParams();   (Zend_Framework).

```
params = {"object":"Main","function":"doecho","params":["echothis%25%5d%22%40%3d%26...."]}
```

What is the best practice here?  Do I need to base64 encode the data?  Is there something obvious I'm missing with the content type or a php setting?

I have full control over the client and server, so I'd like to know what is the right/best thing to do.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

While potentially any content-type can be used to upload to HTTP, there are three used in practice:

1. One specifically set by a given service's documentation.
2. application/x-www-form-urlencoded - the default used by HTML forms.
3. multipart/form-data  - the other form used by HTML forms, required when it includes form uploads.

Due to 2 and 3 being so commonly used (as they are supported by all browser's for submitting forms), pretty much all server-side tech has things to handle them. So unless the PHP part does something strange, you should be able to use either.

application/x-www-form-urlencoded isn't appropriate for some data, but is the simplest for what it is used for. It's pretty much the same as the way query-strings are created for GET form requests, but as POST content.

Hence you want your content to be:

```
"params=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(paramData)
```

As such the first becomes:

```
params=%7B%22object%22%3A%22Main%22%2C%22function%22%3A%22doecho%22%2C%22params%22%3A%5B%22echothis....%22%5D%7D
```

And the second:

```
params=%7B%22object%22%3A%22Ccmes_Main%22%2C%22function%22%3A%22doecho%22%2C%22params%22%3A%5B%22echothis%2525%255d%2522%2540%253d%2526....%22%5D%7D
```

Both of which PHP's built-ins will turn back into the forms in your question.

Comment: Because nit-picking can prevent bugs, note that "params" (but not the "=") should also be URI-encoded. Because I know that "params" when URI-encoded is still "params", I don't as a shortcut, but if it was "párams" or "the params" then it would have to be.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought was encoding it as base64. I think this should be the simplies way.

From [arcanecode.com](http://arcanecode.com/2007/03/21/encoding-strings-to-base64-in-c/):

```
static public string EncodeTo64(string toEncode)
{
  byte[] toEncodeAsBytes = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(toEncode);
  string returnValue = System.Convert.ToBase64String(toEncodeAsBytes);
  return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: If the first example worked, then this can't be correct, since the first example wasn't Base-64.

Comment: Jon Hanna, the EncodeTo64 function (answer of hichaeretaqua) is just for encode the string in a Heximal representation of the ASCII Bytes.